# ssh and edit remote /etc/filesystems with sed

Tags: ssh, sed, escaping, aix

I want to edit /etc/filesystems of several AIX hosts. I want to replace all lines:

```
/usr/sap/interfaces:
dev             = /my_mount/mnt
```

with

```
usr/sap/interfaces:
dev             = "/my_mount/mnt"
```

so far I tried:

```
sed 's/^dev/\/my_mount\/mnt/"\/my_mount\/mnt"/'
```

But it didn't work. I'm trying to do it remotely with ssh so I'm using a command like:

```
ssh username@servername 'sed \'s/^dev/\/my_mount\/mnt/"\/my_mount\/mnt"/' '
```

So what is correct way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `sed '/^dev/s@\(/my_mount/mnt\)@"\1"@'`

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you want to do is change the delimiter you are using in `sed`, as you're trying to match something containing lots of slashes.

The second thing you want to do is change the quoting used in the command passed to ssh, this time because sed likes the apostrophe.  That makes things easier to read.

That should leave you with a command something like this:

```
ssh username@servername "sed '/^dev/s#\(/my_mount/mnt\)#\"\1\"#' /usr/sap/interfaces"
```

If that produces the output you want, then you can change it to actually edit the file, by using the `-i` arg:

```
ssh username@servername "sed -i '/^dev/s#\(/my_mount/mnt\)#\"\1\"#' /usr/sap/interfaces"
```

Note that at this point there's a pretty good chance you'll get an error like `sed: couldn't open temporary file /usr/sap/sedEYALyx: Permission denied` because your normal user account can't write the temporary file required for inline editing.  If that happens, you'll need to add `sudo` in to the command.